# Merging two dataframes in Pandas will create all two dataframes columns in the merged result

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to left `merge` `df1` with `df2` based on three columns `TRADE_ID`, `TRADE_SUB_ID`, and `helper`. `helper` column was created to avoid duplicate rows when merging. Before executing the `merge` function, `df1` has 44 columns. After the `merge`, `df1` now has 122 columns.

```
df1 = df1.merge(df2, how='left', on=['ID', 'SUB_ID', 'helper'], indicator='Result')

df1['Result'] = df1['Result'].map({
    'both': np.nan,
    'left_only': 'under-reporting',
    'right_only': np.nan
})
```

I would like to ask if there is anyway I could merge without creating duplicate columns. Thank you so much.

EDIT:
`df1`looks like such:

```
            ID       SUB_ID  ...                          TIMESTAMP helper
250   G0000001           F1  ...                          48:04.6      0
251   G0000002           F1  ...                          51:25.1      0
252   G0000003           F1  ...                          54:10.6      0
253   G0000006           F1  ...                          03:17.1      0
254   G0000008           F1  ...                          09:23.2      0
       ...          ...  ...                              ...    ...
8610  G0000004           N1  ...                          39:58.2      0
8611  G0000005           F1  ...                          39:58.2      0
8612  G0000005           N1  ...                          39:58.2      0
8641  G0000010           F1  ...                          41:54.1      0
8642  G0000020           N1  ...                          41:54.1      0

[248 rows x 44 columns]
```

And `df2` looks like such:

```
           Type        Primary Key  ...         SUB_ID helper
0          Trade   G000002.00NTSN  ...           00      0
1          Trade  G0000003.F10NTSN  ...           F1      0
2          Trade  G0000006.F10NTSN  ...           F1      0
3          Trade  G0000005.N10NTSN  ...           N1      0
4          Trade  G0000006.F10NTSN  ...           F1      0
..           ...                         ...  ...          ...    ...
163        Trade  G0000007.F10NTSN  ...           F1      0
164        Trade  G0000004.F10NTSN  ...           F1      0
166        Trade  G0000014.F10NTSN  ...           F1      0
167        Trade  G0000006.N10NTSN  ...           N1      0
168        Trade  G0000008.F10NTSN  ...           F1      1

[167 rows x 80 columns]
```

Comment: Please add a minimal sample of your `df1` and `df2` so that the code can be reproducible and add your result and expected results.

Comment: @MaxPierini thanks for the suggestion. Just added in ```df1``` and ```df2``` data. It appears that the 122 columns are the ```df1``` columns and ```df2``` columns added together. However, I do not know how to avoid that.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly the answer you're looking for, but you can easily handle duplicate columns after the fact.

You can do

```
choice = "duplicate_column_name"

### OR ###

choice = ["duplicate_column_name_1", "duplicate_column_name_2", ...]

df.drop(choice, axis=1 , inplace = True)
```

Or if it's easier to do the inverse, you can keep whichever columns you want with

```
df = df[['column_1','column_2']]
```

If I had to guess the resolution to your problem is that you have some kind of duplicate entry in one of your tables.

Comment: thank you so much for the idea. Quick question regarding columns to keep: what if there are duplicate column names in the 122 columns after the merge?

Answer (score 0):

When you do a DataFrame.merge, you're combining the two dataframes on the List,etc, of columns you named. When you do a left merge (SQL equivalent LEFT JOIN) you're keeping all of the left tables keys, but still putting all the columns from the right dataframe into the merge.

My suggestion here is to explicitly declare the columns you want, it may not be the best solution but it will work.

Something to the effect of:

```
COLLIST = [FILL THIS WITH THE COLUMNS YOU WANT]
df2 = df2[[COLLIST]]
df1 = df1.merge(df.2, how = 'left', on = COLLIST)
```

Note this only works if all the columns in df2 are the ones you want to keep.

IF there are different columns the same concept works, just using two different column lists.

There may be a better way, but this is how I would solve this.

Edited to add quickly you can even set the column list by pulling it programatically:

```
collist = df1.index.tolist()
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the suggestion but one quick clarification: for the```on = COLLIST``` part, I used 'ID', 'Sub_id" and 'helper' columns as the unique identifiers. If I am merging on the whole columns, will the unique identifier be gone?

Answer (score 0):

If the duplicated columns are the same in both dataframes, then you should just add them to the `on` list. If you have columns with the same name, but different data, and you want to keep only some of them, you can merge slices of the dataframes. So, for instance

```
df1= df1[['ID', 'SUB_ID', 'helper', col1, col2, col3]].merge(df2[['ID', 'SUB_ID', 'helper', col4]], how='left', on=['ID', 'SUB_ID', 'helper'], indicator='Result')
```

will give you `col1`, `col2`, and `col3` from `df1` but not `df2` and `col4` from `df2` but not `df1`.